# Ethernet DHCP stopped working on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: ethernet, dhcp

I have a notebook running `Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS` for a few months and Ethernet has been working great. Today I just powered on and it fails connecting.

I keep seeing the message `Connection Failed: Activation of network connection failed` popping-up. Information about the system is displayed below.

ethtool:

```
sudo ethtool enp3s0f1
Settings for enp3s0f1:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: d
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                   drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes
```

lshw:

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 10
       serial: d4:6d:6d:81:35:08
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-33-generic firmware=34.0.0 ip=192.168.0.109 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:a4314000-a4317fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.1
       logical name: enp3s0f1
       version: 12
       serial: 80:fa:5b:58:1f:2d
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a4214000-a4214fff memory:a4210000-a4213fff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enx00142dfffffe
       serial: 00:14:2d:ff:ff:fe
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device link=yes multicast=yes
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: docker0
       serial: 02:42:dd:36:7d:0e
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
```

If I try to assign static IP, I am unable to ping the gateway. There are several other computers in the network, getting IP addresses assigned via DHCP, and I can ping the gateway from them, as well as access internet.

I had a look at `dmesg` and there seems to be an issue, but I'm not sure it's related:

```
[  512.317670] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[  512.317674] NETDEV WATCHDOG: enp3s0f1 (r8169): transmit queue 0 timed out
[  512.317704] WARNING: CPU: 4 PID: 0 at /build/linux-81MBYC/linux-4.15.0/net/sched/sch_generic.c:323 dev_watchdog+0x221/0x230
[  512.317706] Modules linked in: rfcomm ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 xt_addrtype iptable_filter xt_conntrack nf_nat nf_conntrack libcrc32c br_netfilter bridge stp llc overlay aufs ccm cmac bnep binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic arc4 uvcvideo btusb videobuf2_vmalloc snd_hda_intel btrtl videobuf2_memops snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm wmi_bmof iwlmvm mxm_wmi serio_raw videobuf2_core snd_hwdep btintel input_leds mac80211 snd_pcm videodev intel_rapl media x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp bluetooth snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event rtsx_pci_ms iwlwifi kvm_intel mei_me snd_rawmidi memstick mei ecdh_generic kvm
[  512.317808]  snd_seq irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc aesni_intel snd_seq_device snd_timer snd aes_x86_64 soundcore crypto_simd glue_helper cfg80211 shpchp wmi intel_pch_thermal cryptd intel_cstate intel_hid intel_rapl_perf acpi_pad sparse_keymap joydev mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid i915 rtsx_pci_sdmmc i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops drm psmouse r8169 ahci rtsx_pci mii libahci video
[  512.317880] CPU: 4 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/4 Not tainted 4.15.0-33-generic #36-Ubuntu
[  512.317883] Hardware name: Notebook                         N8xEJEK                         /N8xEJEK                         , BIOS 1.05.02RNS1 04/13/2018
[  512.317888] RIP: 0010:dev_watchdog+0x221/0x230
[  512.317891] RSP: 0018:ffff912d2d303e58 EFLAGS: 00010286
[  512.317895] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000000006
[  512.317897] RDX: 0000000000000007 RSI: 0000000000000092 RDI: ffff912d2d316490
[  512.317900] RBP: ffff912d2d303e88 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: 00000000000003b5
[  512.317902] R10: ffff912d2d303ee0 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000001
[  512.317905] R13: ffff912d2a8ce000 R14: ffff912d2a8ce478 R15: ffff912d1ed06480
[  512.317909] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff912d2d300000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  512.317912] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  512.317914] CR2: 000055e53468f438 CR3: 000000019be0a002 CR4: 00000000003606e0
[  512.317917] Call Trace:
[  512.317919]  <IRQ>
[  512.317927]  ? dev_deactivate_queue.constprop.33+0x60/0x60
[  512.317935]  call_timer_fn+0x30/0x130
[  512.317942]  run_timer_softirq+0x3fb/0x450
[  512.317947]  ? ktime_get+0x43/0xa0
[  512.317954]  ? lapic_next_deadline+0x26/0x30
[  512.317959]  __do_softirq+0xe4/0x2bb
[  512.317965]  irq_exit+0xb8/0xc0
[  512.317969]  smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x79/0x130
[  512.317976]  apic_timer_interrupt+0x84/0x90
[  512.317978]  </IRQ>
[  512.317985] RIP: 0010:cpuidle_enter_state+0xa7/0x2f0
[  512.317988] RSP: 0018:ffffb19d4196fe68 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff11
[  512.317992] RAX: ffff912d2d322880 RBX: 000000774883164c RCX: 000000000000001f
[  512.317995] RDX: 000000774883164c RSI: fffffffcf772266b RDI: 0000000000000000
[  512.317997] RBP: ffffb19d4196fea8 R08: 00000000ffffffff R09: 0000000000000020
[  512.318000] R10: ffffb19d4196fe38 R11: 00000000000041dd R12: ffff912d2d32cc48
[  512.318002] R13: 0000000000000002 R14: ffffffffbc171bb8 R15: 0000000000000000
[  512.318010]  ? cpuidle_enter_state+0x97/0x2f0
[  512.318016]  cpuidle_enter+0x17/0x20
[  512.318022]  call_cpuidle+0x23/0x40
[  512.318027]  do_idle+0x18c/0x1f0
[  512.318033]  cpu_startup_entry+0x73/0x80
[  512.318038]  start_secondary+0x1ab/0x200
[  512.318044]  secondary_startup_64+0xa5/0xb0
[  512.318047] Code: 38 00 49 63 4e e8 eb 92 4c 89 ef c6 05 a7 13 d9 00 01 e8 c3 36 fd ff 89 d9 48 89 c2 4c 89 ee 48 c7 c7 e8 7d d9 bb e8 1f d6 80 ff <0f> 0b eb c0 90 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 
[  512.318133] ---[ end trace 756930854e9fb9cc ]---
```

As an additional information, the Wi-Fi interface is working. The described issue is only affecting Ethernet.

Currently installed kernel version is `4.15.0-33-generic`:

```
uname -a
Linux leo 4.15.0-33-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 15 16:00:05 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have tried booting from `4.15.0-32-generic` and `4.15.0-30-generic` which are also installed but the issue persists.

Any help debugging this issue is appreciated.

Edit:

I have also tried the mainline kernel `4.18.5-041805-generic` downloaded from the [Ubuntu archive](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D) and installed as described in the [MainlineBuilds article](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds?action=show&redirect=KernelMainlineBuilds), but the issue persists. Everything else worked well.

I have also installed `4.15.0-29-generic` and `4.15.0-24-generic` using apt (including headers, modules and modules-extra packages) and none of those solved the issue.

Edit 2:

dmesg | grep enp:

```
dmesg | grep enp
[    1.844976] r8169 0000:03:00.1 enp3s0f1: renamed from eth0
[    6.947489] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0f1: link is not ready
[    6.998162] r8169 0000:03:00.1 enp3s0f1: link down
[    6.998165] r8169 0000:03:00.1 enp3s0f1: link down
[    6.998237] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0f1: link is not ready
[    9.088158] r8169 0000:03:00.1 enp3s0f1: link up
[    9.088166] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0f1: link becomes ready
[  149.998558] NETDEV WATCHDOG: enp3s0f1 (r8169): transmit queue 0 timed out
[  150.025064] r8169 0000:03:00.1 enp3s0f1: link up
[  494.222007] r8169 0000:03:00.1 enp3s0f1: link down
[  496.328283] r8169 0000:03:00.1 enp3s0f1: link up
[  551.660533] r8169 0000:03:00.1 enp3s0f1: renamed from eth0
[  551.692682] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0f1: link is not ready
[  551.771981] r8169 0000:03:00.1 enp3s0f1: link down
[  551.772077] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0f1: link is not ready
[  553.887435] r8169 0000:03:00.1 enp3s0f1: link up
[  553.887463] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0f1: link becomes ready
```

Edit 3:

I am able to make the Ethernet work, but with a very specific workaround procedure:

To install `r8168-dkms` as suggested by @chili555, I would have to disable secure boot in the system BIOS. I never came to install it, but I did disable secure boot and upon reboot the Ethernet network just connected and worked as expected.

I have further rebooted and noticed that the issue persisted, which was when I discovered the following:

- My BIOS configuration **is being kept** upon reboot. The Secure Boot feature is disabled, no matter how many times I reboot.
- If I enter the BIOS configuration, **change nothing at all**, choose the `save and reset` option, and wait for the system to boot, Ethernet works.
- Even with Secure Boot disabled, if I don't do the procedure described in the previous step, Ethernet don't work.
- This is reproducible booting with regular Ubuntu latest kernel and mainline kernel previously tested (`4.15.0-33-generic`, `4.18.5-041805-generic`).

I have checked early kernel messages using `dmesg` and the following diverge from success and fail:

When Ethernet works:

```
...
[    0.000000] efi:  ACPI 2.0=0x7a039000  ACPI=0x7a039000  SMBIOS=0x7a99b000  SMBIOS 3.0=0x7a99a000  ESRT=0x7521af98  MEMATTR=0x7520f018
...
[    0.000000] esrt: Reserving ESRT space from 0x000000007521af98 to 0x000000007521afd0.
...
[    0.000000] BRK [0x3e413f000, 0x3e413ffff] PGTABLE
[    0.000000] BRK [0x3e4140000, 0x3e4140fff] PGTABLE
[    0.000000] BRK [0x3e4141000, 0x3e4141fff] PGTABLE
[    0.000000] BRK [0x3e4142000, 0x3e4142fff] PGTABLE
[    0.000000] BRK [0x3e4143000, 0x3e4143fff] PGTABLE
[    0.000000] BRK [0x3e4144000, 0x3e4144fff] PGTABLE
[    0.000000] BRK [0x3e4145000, 0x3e4145fff] PGTABLE
[    0.000000] BRK [0x3e4146000, 0x3e4146fff] PGTABLE
[    0.000000] BRK [0x3e4147000, 0x3e4147fff] PGTABLE
[    0.000000] BRK [0x3e4148000, 0x3e4148fff] PGTABLE
...
[    0.000000] Memory: 16143384K/16628012K available (12300K kernel code, 2470K rwdata, 4244K rodata, 2408K init, 2416K bss, 484628K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
...
```

When Ethernet fails:

```
...
[    0.000000] efi:  ACPI 2.0=0x7a039000  ACPI=0x7a039000  SMBIOS=0x7a99b000  SMBIOS 3.0=0x7a99a000  ESRT=0x7521cd18  MEMATTR=0x7520f018
...
[    0.000000] esrt: Reserving ESRT space from 0x000000007521cd18 to 0x000000007521cd50.
...
[    0.000000] BRK [0x125d3f000, 0x125d3ffff] PGTABLE
[    0.000000] BRK [0x125d40000, 0x125d40fff] PGTABLE
[    0.000000] BRK [0x125d41000, 0x125d41fff] PGTABLE
[    0.000000] BRK [0x125d42000, 0x125d42fff] PGTABLE
[    0.000000] BRK [0x125d43000, 0x125d43fff] PGTABLE
[    0.000000] BRK [0x125d44000, 0x125d44fff] PGTABLE
[    0.000000] BRK [0x125d45000, 0x125d45fff] PGTABLE
[    0.000000] BRK [0x125d46000, 0x125d46fff] PGTABLE
[    0.000000] BRK [0x125d47000, 0x125d47fff] PGTABLE
[    0.000000] BRK [0x125d48000, 0x125d48fff] PGTABLE
...
[    0.000000] Memory: 16143392K/16628012K available (12300K kernel code, 2470K rwdata, 4244K rodata, 2408K init, 2416K bss, 484620K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
...
```

Edit 4:

As requested by @heynnema following is the output of `dkms status` (the output is the same when executing with sudo):

```
dkms status
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File:  does not exist.
```

The output of `sudo lshw -c network` is already provided above and has not changed since the question was originally posted.

Edit 5:

Output from `ls -al /var/lib/dkms`

```
leonardo@leo:~$ ls -al /var/lib/dkms
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 set  3 14:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 78 root root 4096 ago 21 08:45 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    6 ago 31  2016 dkms_dbversion
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 jun 18 09:50 nvidia
```

Output from `ls -al /var/lib/dkms/nvidia`

```
leonardo@leo:~$ ls -al /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 jun 18 09:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 set  3 14:16 ..
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 jun 18 08:36 390.67
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   31 jun 18 08:36 kernel-4.13.0-45-generic-x86_64 -> 390.67/4.13.0-45-generic/x86_64
```

p.s. I'm currently using Nouveau open-source driver instead of this nvidia-driver-390.

Output of `ls -al /usr/src`:

```
leonardo@leo:~$ ls -al /usr/src
total 64
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root 4096 set  4 06:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4096 jun 18 12:06 ..
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 set  3 16:37 linux-headers-4.14.67-041467
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 set  3 16:38 linux-headers-4.14.67-041467-generic
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 set  3 16:39 linux-headers-4.14.67-041467-lowlatency
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 set  3 11:27 linux-headers-4.15.0-24
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 set  3 11:27 linux-headers-4.15.0-24-generic
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 set  3 11:05 linux-headers-4.15.0-29
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 set  3 11:05 linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 ago 20 06:51 linux-headers-4.15.0-32
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 ago 20 06:51 linux-headers-4.15.0-32-generic
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 ago 24 06:54 linux-headers-4.15.0-33
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 ago 24 06:54 linux-headers-4.15.0-33-generic
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 set  3 10:39 linux-headers-4.18.5-041805
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 set  3 10:39 linux-headers-4.18.5-041805-generic
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 set  3 10:39 linux-headers-4.18.5-041805-lowlatency
```

Information about the other Ethernet interfaces listed in `sudo lshw -C network`: `*-network:0` is an USB RNDIS interface (which I have unplugged to do all testing and make sure is unrelated) and an interface created by Docker (which I have stopped and disabled the service to make sure is unrelated).

Comment: Please try: `sudo ethtool -s enp3s0f1 autoneg off speed 100` and then try to connect. If it helps, I will propose an answer to make it persistent. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Dear @chili555, thanks for your help. I have tried it, but the issue persists.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `dmesg | grep enp`

Comment: Dear @chili555, I have edited the question. Some points that may be of interest:

 - from the Ubuntu GUI, I have disabled IPv6 for the wired connection - the internal network provides IPv4 address.
 - Even though dmesg tells that the link becomes ready (for IPv6), the IPv4 is not assigned.

Comment: Did you try: `sudo apt install r8168-dkms` I am skeptical but there have been some reports of success. It is easy enough to purge, if it doesn't help.

Comment: Well I did try but I'm being unable to load the driver probably due to secure boot https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules

Comment: Anyway, I'm also skeptical since it was working until two days ago, it isn't as if it never worked or I had a lot of trouble to make it work. I may want to understand which packages have been updated that could make things break.

Comment: apt log or dpkg log will show the updates.

Comment: @chili555 thanks. I checked and in the last few days I didn't see many updates related. Only the kernel update from 4.15.0-32 to 4.15.0-33 but since I already tried booting from the older version and it didn't work, I don't know what could be.

Comment: Please try disabling secure boot and see if r8168 loads and fixes the issue. If not, we'll purge.

Comment: In the process of disabling secure boot Ethernet worked with a very specific procedure. Please see the latest edit to the question, in which "Edit 3" is appended to the end.

Comment: Your workaround using BIOS entry to solve your ethernet problem is really not a good fix. I've had similar problems with 18.04. There may be a bigger Ubuntu bug. **Secure boot = off** is only really required for unsigned kernel modules that are usually added via dkms. The built-in r8169 driver included in Ubuntu is properly signed.

Comment: I had the very same problem with an onboard Realtek chipset of an HP Microtower 500B (PCI-ID 10ec:8136). My workaround was to add a second NIC (no Realtek) and reconfigure the system. Error showed up after upgrading Ubuntu 16 to 18. PXE-Booting Ubuntu 18.1 showed that the mentioned problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar ethernet problem crop up.

Try a different ethernet cable, and a different port on your switch/hub/router, and see if your **link** stays **up** at 1000mbs.

I'm not sure this is a 100% fix, but it's what I did, and my ethernet is working now.

In **terminal**...

```
cd /etc/netplan

sudo pico config.yaml # create the .yaml file and add the following text


network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager


sudo netplan generate

sudo netplan apply

reboot
```

Comment: Thanks @heynnema but this did not work. To revert I have deleted the .yaml file and run the netplan generate and apply commands. Is that enough or any further steps are required?

Comment: @lgraba no extra steps are required, but leaving this configuration will do no harm if you wish to continue using NetworkManager. If you wish to use resolved, you'll need to use a different .yaml file. Check your cabling for a bad/incorrect ethernet cable, or bad ethernet port on your switch/hub/router.

Comment: I just did test the cabling and it works, as well as the router and DHCP. I have made Ethernet work using a very specific workaround, just edited the question with "Edit 3" to describe the procedure.

Comment: Edit your question to include the output of **sudo lshw -c network** and **dkms status** and report back.

Comment: Added the output of dkms status as requested. The output of sudo lswh -c network can be found early in the question and have not changed since then.

Comment: That **dkms status** output doesn't look right. Show me **ls -al /var/lib/dkms** and **ls -al /usr/src**. Are network:0 and network:1 physical ports on your ethernet card, or are you defining those elsewhere? What version r8168-dkms is available to you? 8.0.41-8.0.46?

Comment: sorry, please allow me some time to edit the question and remove the comments.

Comment: I have added the formatted information to the end of the answer. I have ommited the recursive option for **ls -alR /var/lib/dkms** since the only directory there is **nvidia** whose driver is not being used currently. If you really need this info please let me know and I will further edit the question.

Comment: ah... the **dkms status** error is because dkms thinks there's a nvidia driver, but the /usr/src/nividia-390.67 source folder is missing. Do **sudo dkms remove nvidia/390.67 -k kernel-4.13.0-45-generic/x86_64**. See **man dkms** if you need to tweak my **dkms remove** command for your configuration. Is the ethernet cable from your computer plugged into a switch or hub or router or cable modem? Try it directly to the router or cable modem. Did you tell me what r8168-dkms driver you have access to?

Answer (score 0):

After some days I have noticed that the issue was solved. My best bet is that a system update did the trick.

In the meanwhile when the issue was not yet "solved by itself", what I did was enter the BIOS and disable secure boot every time I restarted the machine. It was mandatory, even though my BIOS was keeping the settings.