# Network issues with 18.04 :(

Tags: networking, 18.04, ethernet

Linux noob incoming...

So I have two workstations on the same network (HP Z6 and Z640 if that matters) and did a fresh install of 18.04.1 on both. For some reason, the network connection (ethernet) on both will intermittently die for a minute or so at a time. like when I try loading a page, it will be stuck on "Connecting to x..." for ~1 minute and then go through. This happens on multiple browsers.

Then I reinstalled 16.04 on the Z640 and the problem went away, so it seems something about 18.04 isn't playing well with these workstations. Any ideas on what might be causing this? I'd really like to use 18.04.

I should mention I'm on a work network. IT will not help because they think it's an issue with 18.04.

Comment: Since you are after ideas, perhaps there is a bug in 18.04 or a hardware problem, or some kind of incompatibility. Hope that helps :~). Oh, in case you actually want to try and tackle the problem (just forgot to mention it), adding relevant hardware specs and logs would be a good start.

Comment: Haha sorry, yes, I'd like to tackle the problem. It's an HP Z6 with the Intel I219-LM ethernet adapter (the Z640 is now on 16.04 and works). Not sure what else is relevant so here's the full lshw if helpful: https://pastebin.com/WTsV72Y8     How do I get the useful logs?

Comment: I'd add the output of `lspci -nnk`, and for logs, `dmesg -T | tail -n20` at the time the connection dies. Also, syslog and kern.log might be useful, ...and logs are in /var/log, by the way.

Comment: lspci -nnk: https://pastebin.com/13Mf6d8W

dmesg: https://pastebin.com/x2HYhBLZ

syslog: https://pastebin.com/Tf4fUcsB

kern.log: https://pastebin.com/VsuiA46A

I don't think there were new entries, though. The connection died around 15:17

Comment: See my answer at [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071668/ethernet-dhcp-stopped-working-on-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts/1071837#1071837). Please remember to vote for it if it was helpful. Thanks! Also, none of the logs that you provided show the information around 15:17.